# Spring Boot Controller not mapping (Whitelabel Error Page)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a Spring REST project that is redirecting all requests to error page, even if they are mapped in the controller.

I reduced the code to the smallest possible version that produces the error:

Here is the project structure:

[image]

Here is the Application class (The imports are removed to make the thread easier to read):

```
package com.example.demo;

@Controller
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }


    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    @ResponseBody
    public String greeting() {
        return "greeting";
    }

}
```

Originally I hade a sperate controller from the App class, but moved the controller code to the app class to make sure that this is not a project structure problem
Here is the controller code (Tried with and without it, and received the same error):

```
@Controller
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }


    @GetMapping("/hello")
    @ResponseBody
    public String greeting() {
        return "greeting";
    }

}
```

(Both  http://localhost:8080/greeting as well as well http://localhost:8080/hello return the same error page)

Dependencies and plugins from the pom file:

```
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
```

(Tried with and without tomcat as dependency and nothing changed)

And lastly here is the error message I receive in the browser when I visit the links (http://localhost:8080/greeting and http://localhost:8080/hello):

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Nov 27 00:16:08 CET 2022
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

**Edit:**
After setting debug to true in project.properties, here is the error message I see in console (Worth mentioning that the project ran with no issues when I tried it on another system (Same OS)):

```
 GET "/greeting", parameters={}
 Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
 Resource not found
 Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
 "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
```

(Timestamps are removed to make reading easier)

Comment: debug=true helped me in similar scenarios. Also share us the application properties. If it is possible, a GitHub repository to help you

Comment: How are you running the app? Shell or Eclipse?

Comment: My "application properties" file is completely empty in this miniature project of the original. I am running the app in Eclips (actually in STS). Will set debug to true and upload the code on GitHub when I get home. Thanks.

Comment: @JRichardsz: I updated the original post with error message I see in console after activating the debug flag

Comment: Share us the code and I will fix it. I think the problem is in your package

Comment: Here is the code::
https://github.com/ramy670/TestProject

Comment: Repository is empty or dont exist

Comment: Forgot to make it public, sorry about that. Repo is now public.

Comment: Did you found that everything was as it should? (i.e nothing to correct)

Comment: Not related to the question but your github code has one error in the main: SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);.. it should be **TestApplication**. Also I downloaded your code and ran it. Rest controllers work as expected:  https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/3322836/205496303-767b3bfc-ed2f-4a2d-be15-6f3ee0f2a8a9.png  Are you on windows? Try on linue, try with eclipse instead STS, try with shell mvn spring-boot:run  Share the result updating the question, not as comments

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried making call to the endpoint via postman ? If so, can you try again after removing @ResponseBody annotation.

Comment: I tried, same error. I removed @ ReponseBody and replaced @ Controller with @ RestController but still received the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of @Controller use @RestController

Comment: I had @RestController at start (Without @ReponseBody), also same error.